# Meaning and usages: Simple or Simplistic

Tags: word-choice

It is ......... to see mob violence mere a law and order problem.

- simple
- simplistic

What's the difference in simple and simplistic? Which one fits here.

Comment: This can be answered by looking up the two words in the dictionary. If you are still unsure about the difference, please can you edit your post to explain why and quote your sources.

Comment: @Bee This is question of my test. I am confused between two words.

Comment: *To see mob violence mere a law and order problem* is ungrammatical. As best as I can tell, it should be *to see mob violence **as merely** a law and order problem*. But if this is the *exact* wording of the test, the test is dubious to start with. And aside from this grammar issue, *both* words fit. Barring additional context that hasn't been provided, it's not possible to pick one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the definitions:

**[simplistic](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/simplistic)**: *adjective* treating complex issues and problems as if they were much simpler than they really are.

**[simple](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/simple)**: *adjective* easily understood or done; presenting no difficulty.

---

Now, let's try each in the sentence you provided to see which one makes more sense:

**Simple**:

> "It is [a word meaning "easily understood"] to see mob violence mere a law and order problem."

This doesn't really fit because it doesn't fit the context of the rest of the sentence, which implies that "mob violence" is a complex issue.

**Simplistic**:

> "It is [a word meaning "treating complex issues and problems as if they were much simpler than they really are"] to see mob violence mere a law and order problem."

This sentence would makes sense. So it's okay to use "simplistic" here.